# Problems compiling kernel on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel

I'm trying to compile the kernel from source on the Raspberry Pi, so I fetched it from **git@github.com:raspberrypi/linux.git**, and I'm using the **stable branch** (**rpi-3.6.y**).

I did the following:

1. `git clone git@github.com:raspberrypi/linux.git`
2. `cd linux`
3. `make mrproper`
4. `zcat /proc/config.gz > .config`
5. `make oldconfig`
6. `make menuconfig`
7. `make`

And during the build process I'm getting the following errors:

```
CC [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.o
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c:20:42: fatal error: linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [net/ipv4/netfilter] Error 2
make[1]: *** [net/ipv4] Error 2
make: *** [net] Error 2
```

I'm using Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #545 PREEMPT) and GCC version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1).

Comment: Have you tried getting the source again ? It looks like it didn't get everything as it's missing files. Or you could try compiling the kernel without using that ipt_ECN module.

Comment: Yeah -- I haven't had any such problems with that source.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I'm working with Mac, and the reason was that Mac is not a case-sensitive OS, so when I download the source, `ipt_ECN.h` was deleted because there was a file called `ipt_ecn.h` (for Mac it is the same so one is deleted). The solution was to make a case-sensitive image disk and download the source there.

I know you are not using Mac, but I hope this will help you. PS: I followed the guide *[Raspberry Pi Kernel Compilation](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation)*.

Comment: They are probably closely related, but isn't the real reason different filesystems ([HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) on Mac?)? Can't a case-sensitive filesystem be used on Mac (it is based on Unix after all)?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer of Nilar.

To get my kernel compiled and workaround the error message:

`net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c:20:42: fatal error: linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

I downloaded the following files:

- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h`
- `include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h`
- `net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c`
- `net/netfilter/xt_HL.c`
- `net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c`
- `net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c`

from:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.12.y

and put them in my source tree. (Then I executed the make command.)

These 3 files somehow got lost when using the git clone command on my Mac as described in a previous answer by Nilar.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I think this is a bit messier than it should be. Someone was walked through the process on #raspbian ([log here](http://plugwash.raspbian.org/logs/index.php?date=2013-08-23)), search for user Foxdie and jump through the same hoops they had to.

Comment: It would be better if you provided a summary here.

Comment: @PeterMortensen if you really believe so, feel free to go ahead and do so

Answer (score -2):

FAT and NTFS file system:
"lowercase" = "uppercase ". (e.g. ipt_ecn.h = ipt_ECN.h)
if you clone "linux" from git, files with uppercase will be disappear.

DO NOT make the working directory in these format.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. What are you trying to say?